# Selenium Grid Test between Windows and Mac

Tags: java, windows, macos, safari, selenium-grid

I'm trying to do a simple Selenium test where the hub is a windows computer and the node is a mac, I'm trying to run the test on Safari on the mac, but I get an error in the console of the node (it's copied below), and the browser doesn't even start.

Hub: Windows 10, 64 bits computer

Node: Mac computer. OS X El Capitan. version 10.11.6

Browser: Safari, version 11.1.2 (11605.3.8.1)

ERROR: required authorization rights are missing or incorrect, but
they cannot be repaired from the command line unless run as root.
To fix these rights, re-run safaridriver using sudo(8) and pass the
'--enable' flag. For more information, see the safaridriver(1) man page.

Any idea of what is wrong or what should I do? any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!